TYPO3 indexed_search not set parameter
I have written my own extension. With a list and show action. If I want to call up the show page, it works via the list page.
domain.com/detail?tx_test_show[action]=show&tx_test_show[controller]=Test&tx_test_show[uid]=137166&cHash=623c4ccbafa5b66c1e09ec3b2a2fd812
But if I search for it in the search with indexed_search, the link is in the search without GET parameters from Extbase. This means that the link doesn't work either.
domain.com/detail
What have I forgotten? With a link source, if you like.
TYPO3 12.4.13
I have regenerated indexed_search entries.
I googled it, but I'm missing the approach.

I'm not too familiar with the extension indexed_search but I assume you are also using the crawler extension to index your content. Take a look at this: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/main/en-us/IndexingConfigurations/Index.html, https://docs.typo3.org/p/tomasnorre/crawler/main/en-us/Configuration/Examples/News/Index.html
Route enhancers might also be a reason why your detail page isn't being indexed: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#routing-extbase-plugin-enhancer

Indexed Search out of the box runs only for pages, not for database records (like e.g. news or your extension).
You need to setup a indexer configuration for your records, where you also need to add the GET parameters needed for the detail view.
See: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/main/en-us/IndexingConfigurations/PeriodicIndexingRecords/Index.html#periodic-indexing-of-records-database-records
(The screenshots are very old, but you should find it)
Edit: Found an installation with indexed_search. Here is a v12 screenshot:

